# FCM Message from Android app to Browser

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Firebase Hosting** running my Website build with Angular and **Firebase Messaging**.

If I sent a FCM to the **browser** via CURL it is working and the message will be shown (see curl example at the bottom).

**Android** app has also added the Firebase Messaging and can receive a message from the Website running on Firebase Hosting.

So far so good, but now I want to send a FCM message **to the browser from the Android app**.

But I don't find any good way to do this on Android.
The Android API FirebaseMessaging and RemoteMessage only accepts an **global** "sender_id" and no **"to"** address like in the CURL or HTTP Request POST.

It is working if I use the HTTP POST Request but in this case I need the Server-API-Key inside my Android App (not good!!) (see HTTP example at the bottom).

So is there any way to send via Android app a FCM message directly to a specific device (in my case the browser)?

---

curl call I use to test if the browser site is working:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<API-KEY>"  -X POST -d "{\"data\": { \"score\": \"5x1\",\"time\": \"15:10\"},\"to\" : \"<token from the browser>\"}" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

HTTP Call inside Android App for testing:

```
try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=<API-KEY>");
                    String postJsonData = "{\"to\": \"<token from the browser>\", \"data\": {\"data\": \"" + data.getNote() + "\"}}";
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(postJsonData);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();

                    int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                    log.i(TAG, "POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

                    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                        log.i(TAG, "succeeded");
                    }
                } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
                    log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException" , e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.e(TAG, "IOException" , e);
                }
```

Comment: Please use boldface more sparingly. **It** can **become** distracting and **makes the** text more **difficult** to **read**.

Comment: Changed, sorry. I have really made A LOT in bold ;-)

Answer (score 0):

deploy your code in firebase functions with server keys, hit it from you android app.

Comment: Yes this is also an alternative. But I wonder if there exists any way to do this without cloud functions. The same as I do with the webpage to the android app.

Comment: nope! if you want to hit google fcm server then, server key is must,